# Joins com entidades filhas

Tags: java, hql

Eu tenho uma entidade pai que se chama OCR, esta tem 2 que são especialização(herança): OCR_A, OCR_B.

Meu hql precisa contemplar as 2, ou seja, preciso dar join nas 2. Eu começo assim:

```
select o from OCR o
```

Como faço `join` nas 2 tabelas filhas? Obs: O ID de cada uma é herdado da entidade OCR.

Answer (score 0):

Sua busca pela tabela pai automaticamente vai trazer as tabelas filhas, independentemente da sua consulta.

Por qual motivo? O framework (digamos o Hibernate) não sabe se você, depois de pegar a entidade pai, vai querer fazer (ou tentar) um *cast* para algumas das entidades filhas, então ele já se precavê desta situação.

Se você pedir para exibir o SQL desta consulta, verá que as tabelas filhas também estarão na consulta através de um `LEFT JOIN`. Algo assim, se estiver usando a estratégia de *JOIN table* para herança:

```
SELECT ocr.*, ocra.*,ocrb.* FROM OCR ocr
LEFT JOIN OCR_A ocra ON ocra.id = ocr.id
LEFT JOIN OCR_B ocrb ON ocrb.id = ocr.id
```

Se estiver usando a estratégia *SINGLE table*, todas as informações ficam na mesma tabela, então verá no SQL apenas uma tabela:

```
SELECT ocr.* FROM OCR ocr
```